# Create a system select from different lists and then make a total in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, arraylist, plugins, formula

I know, the question isn't clear in itself. Let me explain.

I want to create a system where a visitor can choose options from different lists and result will be the total amount with all the details of the selected components.

Theoretically it's a simple formula but i have no idea how to apply it on wordpress. i am not even on moderate level in programming.

So, anyone has any idea, how it can be achieved, any plugin or functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your not comfortable coding this is a bit tough. It sounds like you're talking about some type of store (total amount?). A list of items with details and price and lists of add ons or features that change the price and product configuration? Something like that?

Coding this would I think be a bunch of jQuery/javascript. Otherwise try the Gravity Forms plugin (which I've used and should be able to do this for you) or perhaps a straight ecommerce plugin - there are lots. Then I think you just have to learn the plugin to get the setup you want.

Comment: First Thanks for looking into it.

Actually i am not going for ecommerce or product/price road. 

I have 3-4 lists of categorized components. what i want to do is, the visitor can select a component from each list and the result area shows him total weight of these. just this. nothing to process in terms of price, selling or anything. it just information of total weight with selected components. so the visitor can note the result and use the components he like. much more like a recipe.

Comment: can it be achieved through radio button lists and adding a formula with list id's or something.